# Download git master repository in php

Tags: php, git, curl

I would like to download the git master.zip to a directory in php code. I am using cURL to download it and the code I have works, so that aspect is working. I am wondering how to get the correct file from some master URL such as

```
https://github.com/{group}/{project}/archive/master.zip
```

The file I recieve has only 1 byte of information, and I am wondering where I am going wrong. Here is the code I am using for my download

```
<?php
//just an example repository
$url = 'https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife/archive/master.zip';

$fh = fopen('master.zip', 'w');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // this will follow redirects
curl_exec($ch);

print 'Attempting download of '.$url.'<br />';
if(curl_error($ch) == '')
    $errors = '<u>none</u>';
else
    $errors = '<u>'.curl_error($ch).'</u>';
print 'cURL Errors : '.$errors;

curl_close($ch);

fclose($fh);
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: i received the whole file

Comment: Strange, I received the file too on the test repository, but not on the actual repository that I will be fetching from. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: hard to say without really experiencing the problem to begin with

Comment: what's wrong with `file_get_contents()` ? `curl` isn't required here

Comment: I realized it might be a problem with the size of the file. Does cURL only allow a limit on file transfers?

Comment: The code I tried for file_get_contents() refused the connection from the github server.

Comment: @hek2mgl everything is wrong with file_get_contents() ;)

Comment: @JeslyVarghese Please explain. `file_get_contents()` is the preferred method for making GET requests

Comment: @JohnSmith: php.ini file got some size constraints.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I exaggerated that a bit ;). But AFAIK https is not so easy on file_get_contents + most shared hosts doesn't allow it coz of security reasons.

Comment: I had no problems using this code: `php -r 'file_put_contents("master.zip", file_get_contents("https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump/archive/master.zip"));'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `allow_url_fopen` is set to `On` in the `php.ini` you can simply use `file_get_contents()`. No curl is required in this case. I successfully downloaded a `master.zip` of one of my repositories using:

```
file_put_contents("master.zip", 
    file_get_contents("https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump/archive/master.zip")
);
```

Comment: Yes I have my php.ini file properly set. I realized it might be because I am trying to get the master.zip from a private repository. I do not have control of the repository, so is there any way to do this with a private repository?

Comment: I guess that private means *private* ;)